# Issue compiling a piece of open source software written in C++ on MacOS Sierra

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, command-line, g++

I am trying to install a piece of open source software ([AB3P](https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/Ab3P)) on MacOS Sierra. When I issue the command `make` I get this error: `ld: library not found for -lops`. The make command issued before the error is thrown is: `g++ -g -o make_wordSet make_wordSet.o -L./Library -lops -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -lpthread`

I have the latest version of MacOS Sierra and Xcode + the Xcode command line developer tools (as of this writing). In addition `gcc` is installed, the command `gcc --version` returns:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I am not sure how to approach the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: The line you posted does not resemble anything in that project's makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Get into Library folder, and make it first.

`cd Library
make`

There it will find the libops.a

On the updated version of the Ab3P as @ridoro1 mentioned, you need to make first NCBITextLib and edit the both Makefiles under Ab3P and also under Library.

First get into Library and make it. Then make Ab3P.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download [this](https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/NCBITextLib) library and compile it, then edit `Makefile` in the folder of this library and the `Makefile` in the `lib` folder inside it to point to `NCBITextLib-master` folder on your disk, after that You can compile the ABP3 library.